# C# database Access not validating

Tags: c#, sql, database, authentication

Please help me, Im getting ---MessageBox.Show("Login NOT Successfull, Try again!"); ----everytime I put the right username and pass. What can  be the problem? Thanks

I seems it dosent want to validate..

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace posSystem
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {



                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=userName.accdb");

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From userAndPass Where ID = @id AND pass = @password", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtBoxUserName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtBoxPassword.Text);
                conn.Open();

                OleDbDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if(re.Read())
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull"); 



                }
                else{
                MessageBox.Show("Login NOT Successfull, Try again!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified that your username and password exist in the database?

Comment: Try to run the equivalent sql directly in your database to verify that the record exists

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

Try to change your query like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From userAndPass Where ID = ? AND pass = ?", conn);
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your answer but it still dosent work any other help?

Comment: That's not really true.  You can use named parameters, but they will be treated as if they were '?'.  The order of the parameters have to match in the same order as the values get supplied.